# Creating a Stock Chart in Crystal Reports with a DataTable from C# Program

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a chart that is displayed in my WinForms program that I need to display on a Crystal Report. The data has one value (Slump) that is the x-axis value, and corresponding pairs of values (Min, Max) that are shown as a range for each Slump value. In VS I am using a Range Column chart, but as there is no such thing in CR, Stock Chart is the best option.

The data is sent to the CR in a DataTable, where each row contains Slump, Min, and Max values. I have set up the stock chart as CR recommends, where "On Change Of" is Slump (x-axis) and "Show Values" are Min and Max. This does not work whatsoever. I can't find any documentation on how to use this specific chart in CR. Below are some images of what I have:
[[image: Data Settings for Stock Chart]]
[[image: Chart in VS]]
[image: Chart in CR]
I want to make the CR Chart look close to what the VS Chart looks like. They use the same data. I've tried changing the summary operation in CR, to no avail. I've tried every combination I can think of for the parameters in the Chart Expert. Does anyone know if what I want to do is possible?